# Can I filter certain events out from Sentry reporting on Android?

Tags: android, sentry

I would like to not sent 400s or certain Exception types to Sentry. Is that possible? The [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/configuration/filtering/) doesn't make it clear how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you shared there's this snippet:

```
SentryAndroid.init(this, options -> {
  options.setBeforeSend((event, hint) -> {
    if (event.getThrowable() instanceof SQLiteException) {
      event.setFingerprints(Arrays.asList("database-connection-error"));
    }
    return event;
  });
});
```

Here you can drop events that were created with the exception type `SQLiteException`.

If you want to send 1 and drop the rest, you'd need to write some code. Like hold a hashmap of Type and add the exceptions to it as they go through this callback. And if it's a hit, you drop the event.